# Convex optimisation and non-globally convex functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose I am maximising some function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=0 \iff x=c$. However 
 $f''(x)<0 \iff c-k<x<c+k$ for some positive real number $k$. Even though the second order condition holds locally, is the inference that $x=c$ is a maximum still permitted?

Comment: Is the function differentiable everywhere?   If so, you can use the mean value theorem.  If not, then you can draw some simple counter-examples.

Comment: Yes it is differentiable everywhere. How would I apply the mean-value theorem here?

Comment: Do you agree that $f(x)<f(c)$ for $x$ in an interval about $c$ (and $x\neq c$)? (So, a local max?)

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: So you might consider what happens if there is some point $y\neq x$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Okay, then what? What does that imply about whether or not $x=c$ is a maximum?

Comment: What do you mean "Then what"?  Have you considered what happens?

Comment: if $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\neq y$ then, the function has the same value at two different points. If $f(y)>f(c)$ then $x=c$ is not a global maximum. But I don't see how this relates to $x=c$ being a maximum in general (including local maximum)?

Comment: So you have decided to ignore the mean value theorem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I don't really understand. I looked up that theorem and I did not follow how it relates.

Comment: What happens if $f(a)=f(b)$?

Comment: I suppose neither $a$ nor $b$ represent global maxima?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69257/discussion-between-pafnuti-and-michael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $f$ is sufficiently smooth (i.e. $C^2$), you can conclude that

1) either $f$ attains its maximum at a local maximum, or never attains its maximum but keeps increasing towards the boundary of its domain (in this case $\pm\infty$);

2) $x=c$ is the unique local maximum of $f$;

3) $f$ is decreasing in both directions away from $c$. This is because $f'<0$ at $x=c+k$ since
$$f'(c+k) = f'(c) + \int_c^{c+k} f''(x)\,dx < 0$$
and $f'(x)$ must remain negative for $x\in (c+k,\infty)$ since otherwise by the intermediate value theorem $f'(x) = 0$ for some $x\in (c+k,\infty)$, violating the condition that $x=c$ is the unique critical point of $f$. An exact same argument applies when $x<c$.